# Как указать универсальный путь для файла

Tags: файлы, html, php

Как указать универсальный путь для файла в `php/html` например у меня файл у меня находится в `/tpl/index.thml`, а `css` файл у меня в `/tpl/css/style.css` все это мне нужно в файле `/Index.php` и чтобы `index.html` видел `style.css` без определения папки `/tpl/` и самого адреса типа http://example.com/tpl/css/style.css можно ли такое сделать

Comment: Совсем не ясна суть вопроса.

Вы хотите узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при запросе на http://example.com/style.css брался файл из `/tpl/css/style.css`?

Или вы хотите узнать, как сделать так, чтобы при генерации HTML вместо  `<link href="/tpl/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` было `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`?

Answer (score 1):

Хм, я конечно всех тонкостей не знаю. Единственное что нестандартное в голову приходит - это создать некий style.php, который в зависимости от параметра возвращал бы нужный стиль.

К примеру по запросу `http://site/style.php?cmd=tpl` будет возвращать файл содержащий текст по ссылке `http://example.com/tpl/css/style.css`

Как мне известно у html-ки трудно (если возможно) скрыть ссылки на css-ки

Comment: неее, мне нужно в html коде типа ../../ только почему то у меня не работает

Answer (score 1):

Эм, один вопрос: зачем это?
Вообще - у HTML нельзя сокращать ссылки, это нужно делать посредством php-файла (роутинг)

Если уж совсем нужно, можете создать файл (роутер), который будет пересылать на нужный файл по запросу (GET), при этом проверяя откуда пришел запрос. Данный метод будет полезен тем, кто не хочет светить свои css и js-файлы. Но это бред, имхо.

Comment: ааа если нет не обходимости не несветить файлы. тогда ок.

Comment: я просто подумал светить папками /tpl/ не красиво и задал вопрос.